# C# Programming How to not filter our spaces within directories using Regular expression?

Tags: c#, regex, whitespace, tokenize

I have a program which utilizes both tokenize and Regular expressions to filter out both spaces (' ') and "," from a log file string.

However as there are spaces located within a log file string directory, so may someone please offer some advice regarding the regular expressions that I could use?  Thanks!

*Please not that there are SPACES and COMMAS due to the date, time and contents that have to be tokenized! DO NOT ASSUME THAT I PLACED THE SPACES FOR FUN and start giving negative votes! Like someone.

One such string line of the log text file would be:

```
Thu Mar 02 1995 21:31:00,2245107,m...,r/rrwxrwxrwx,0,0,8349-128-3,C:/Program Files/AccessData/AccessData Forensic Toolkit/Program/wordnet/Adj.dat
```

The results output of the program would be"

```
Thu
Mar
02
1995
21:31:00
2245107
m...
r/rrwxrwxrwx
0
0
8349-128-3
C:/Program
Files/AccessData/AccessData
Forensic
Toolkit/Program/wordnet/Adj.dat
```

Therefore the "C:/Program Files/AccessData/AccessData Forensic Toolkit/Program/wordnet/Adj.dat" is seperated due to the spaces regular expressions.

The program codes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


namespace Testing
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

      String value = "Thu Mar 02 1995 21:31:00,2245107,m...,r/rrwxrwxrwx,0,0,8349-128-
      3,C:/Program Files/AccessData/AccessData Forensic 
      Toolkit/Program/wordnet/Adj.dat";
        //
        // Split the string on line breaks.
        // ... The return value from Split is a string[] array.
        //

        //foreach (String r in lines)
        //{
            String rex = @"[\s,]";

            String[] token = Regex.Split(value, rex);

            foreach (String line in token)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
        //}
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why are you splitting by spaces? It looks like commas are the only separators in that sample line. (And can filenames have commas in?)

Comment: Dude...Its pretty obvious as there is a time involved? As mentioned in the above its a LOG TEXT FILE STRING so obviously is a MACtimes log file. MACtimes is a forensics timeline based log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't split on spaces, they are part of the values.

```
string value = "Thu Mar 02 1995 21:31:00,2245107,m...,r/rrwxrwxrwx,0,0,8349-128-3,C:/Program Files/AccessData/AccessData Forensic Toolkit/Program/wordnet/Adj.dat";
string[] token = value.Split(',');
foreach (String line in token) {
  Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

If you want the components of the date as separate values, you can split that on spaces:

```
string[] dateCompent = token[0].Split(' ');
```

Comment: I need both the spaces and "," split due to the time, date and content. Can you help me with that? Thanks.

Comment: @JavaNoob: First split on comma only, then you can take the date and time value and split on spaces to get it's separate compontents.

Comment: Is it possible to do all the various filters on 1 single regular expressions? That would really help alot. Thanks.

Comment: I think your answer would just work as well. Thanks for the answer mate.

Answer (score 0):

If you *have* to do it in a single regex, and if the only instance where you *do* want to split on spaces is in the first item (i. e. the date string), then you can do

```
splitArray = Regex.Split(subjectString, @",|(?<=^[^,]*)\s+");
```

This regex splits either on a comma or on a space, but only if that space doesn't follow a comma somewhere before in the string.

**Explanation:**

```
,       # match a ,
|       # or
(?<=    # assert that it is possible to match the following before the current position:
 ^      # start of string
 [^,]*  # any number of characters except commas
)       # end of positive lookahead assertion
```

Be aware, though, that filenames might contain commas, too (at least they are legal there - whether they do appear in your data is something only you can judge).
    \s+     # then match one or more whitespace characters